# Running R in Scala using rscala causing issues

Tags: r, scala

I recently came across an R package called rscala. https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/tag/rscala/

I tried executing the example however the program never completed running. I am not sure what may be wrong. Whenever I try to instantiate RClient, it seems to run forever. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following code runs:

```
import breeze.stats.distributions._
import breeze.linalg._
import org.ddahl.rscala.RClient

object ScalaToRTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // first simulate some data consistent with a Poisson regression model
    val x = Uniform(50,60).sample(1000)
    val eta = x map { xi => (xi * 0.1) - 3 }
    val mu = eta map { math.exp }
    val y = mu map { Poisson(_).draw }

    // call to R to fit the Poission regression model
    val R = RClient() // initialise an R interpreter
    R.x=x.toArray // send x to R
    R.y=y.toArray // send y to R
    R.eval("mod <- glm(y~x,family=poisson())") // fit the model in R
    // pull the fitted coefficents back into scala
    val beta = DenseVector[Double](R.evalD1("mod$coefficients"))

    // print the fitted coefficents
    println(beta)    
  }

}
```

Output:

```
DenseVector(-3.1683714618415855, 0.1031332817387318)
```

*build.sbt*

```
name := "scalaRdemo"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % "0.13.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.13.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.ddahl" %% "rscala" % "2.3.5"
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this and let you know

Comment: It compiles fine but not running. Does this depend on R version? I have  R version 3.1.3.

Comment: @user8654291 I installed R and RStudio from here: https://cran.r-project.org/
`R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)`
`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/`
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install r-base`
`sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/
`rstudio-1.0.136-amd64.deb`

If it doesn't run what is exception?

Comment: There is no exception. It just does not give an output. Even if I run it for more than a hour. I have an older R version will try with this.

Comment: Oh Actually I was using rscala jar 2.11 for scala 2.10. That was causing the issues for me. Once i started using 2.10 jar it worked fine for me.