# Calling R function inside Spark Scala?

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Gabriel graph for point dataset using cccd (Class Cover Catch Digraphs library)  in R, but I want to call this code from Spark Scala as I have to apply some clustering algorithms from MLlib on the generated graph, How can I call R code from Scala? or Can I move the R code to SparkR and call it from Spark Scala?

Comment: I can't say regarding Spark, but regarding your question how to call R code from Scala I tried rscala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459618/running-r-in-scala-using-rscala-causing-issues

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thank you for the response, I would try the suggested approach and will check it.