# How to execute R function through Spark Dataframe in Scala

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark

Below code is returning empty rows. How to execute R function on a Spark Dataframe using Scala

```
val myRFunction = """

        myRFunction <- function(x) {

            y <- x*2

            return(y)

        }

"""

val r = org.ddahl.rscala.RClient()

r.eval(myRFunction)

val result = r.eval("myRFunction(10)")

println(result)
```

Trying to execute R function through Scala

Comment: Maybe you could try to wrap the RClient call in an [UDF](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-udf/).

Comment: Tried to wrap RClient in UDF and invoked UDF from a Spark dataframe, Still getting empty rows. RClient is not working as expected.

val r = RClient()
r.eval(myRFunction)
r.x = x -- This line is throwing error

Comment: What error does it raise? Give us the complete details.

Comment: @Surya What is your `build.sbt`? Please double check that you're everywhere using Scala either 2.13 or 2.12 or 2.11 but not their mix  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459618/running-r-in-scala-using-rscala-causing-issues

Comment: I am using rscala_2.12-3.2.19 , Spark3.2 cluster.
r.x = x throws error message: value x is not a member or "org.ddahl.rscala.RClient"

Comment: @Surya Yeah, I do not mean that you should copy the code from that my answer. My understanding is that API changed since then. Then it was 2.3.5, now it is 3.2.19. Just in comments, that-question OP confirmed that their issues were caused by mixing `_2.10` and `_2.11` for Scala and rscala jars. You're using `_2.12` rscala, so your Scala version should be 2.12.x (e.g. 2.12.17).

Comment: Below is the exception I am getting using above code.  Please provide me a reference to invoke a R function from Scala

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported
  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.schemaForTypeUnsupportedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1008)